# Behaviour of xsl:value-of inside an xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt-1.0

I seem to have problem retrieving the value of a node when the node name is the value of another node in the same document.  Let me illustrate.

First the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Doc>
    <Schools>
        <School>
            <Id>5489</Id>
            <Name>St Thomas</Name>
            <Address>High Street, London, England</Address>
        </School>
        <School>
            <Id>7766</Id>
            <Name>Anderson Boys School</Name>
            <Address>Haymarket, Edinborough</Address>
        </School>
    </Schools>
    <FamilySmith>
        <Children>
            <Child>
                <Name>Thomas</Name>
                <School_Id>5489</School_Id>
            </Child>
            <Child>
                <Name>Andrew</Name>
                <School_Id>7766</School_Id>
            </Child>
        </Children>
    </FamilySmith>
</Doc>
```

I simply want to display the following:
  Thomas goes to St Thomas at High Street, London, England.
  Andrew goes to Anderson Boys School at Haymarket, Edinborough

Using the folollowing xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>

        <xsl:template match="/Doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FamilySmith"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FamilySmith">
        <xsl:for-each select="Children/Child">
            <xsl:text>&#xa; </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:text> goes to </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Doc/Schools/School[Id = School_Id]/Name"/>
            <xsl:text> at </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Doc/Schools/School[Id = School_Id]/Address"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it seems that the expression /Doc/Schools/School[Id = School_Id]... does not work as it returns an empty value each time.  The results are given below.

Thomas goes to  at 
 Andrew goes to  at

Any offers pleaese?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`current()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Doc/Schools/School[Id = current()/School_Id]/Name"/>
```

Your previous attempt was looking for School elements that have an `Id` and a `School_Id` child that have the same value, whereas what you actually want is to compare the School's Id against the `School_Id` child of the `Child` that is the target of the current iteration of the `for-each`, i.e. the *current context node from outside the predicate*. This is what `current()` gives you.