# Using xsl:value-of in for-each loop over a xsl:variable

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-variable

This is a sequel to the question in entry [25317199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317199/behaviour-of-xslvalue-of-inside-an-xslfor-each).

In the 25317199 post, the data has 2 blocks, i.e., *Schools* and *FamilySmith*.  Data in *FamilySmith* is used as the key to retrieve the data in *Schools*.

Now, in this case, the data is split in that *FamilySmith* is now defined as a **variable** inside the stylesheet, as illustrated below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="FamilySmith">
        <Children>
            <Child>
                <Name>Thomas</Name>
                <School_Id>5489</School_Id>
            </Child>
            <Child>
                <Name>Andrew</Name>
                <School_Id>7766</School_Id>
            </Child>
        </Children>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/Doc">
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($FamilySmith)/Children/Child">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:text> goes to (school's name here) </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Doc/Schools/School[Id = current()/School_Id]/Name"/>
            <xsl:text> at (school's address here) </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Doc/Schools/School[Id = current()/School_Id]/Address"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is applied to the XML data below:

```
<Doc>
    <Schools>
        <School>
            <Id>5489</Id>
            <Name>St Thomas</Name>
            <Address>High Street, London, England</Address>
        </School>
        <School>
            <Id>7766</Id>
            <Name>Anderson Boys School</Name>
            <Address>Haymarket, Edinborough</Address>
        </School>
    </Schools>
</Doc>
```

Both retrievals of school's name and school's address produce empty strings, as shown below.

```
Thomas goes to (school's name here)  at (school's address here) 
Andrew goes to (school's name here)  at (school's address here)
```

I have used the advice given in the previous posting [25317199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317199/behaviour-of-xslvalue-of-inside-an-xslfor-each), i.e., using current() to identify "current context node from outside the predicate." But it seems that the problem lies elsewhere.  Please advise.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that absolute paths starting with `/` resolve relative to the root node of *the tree containing the current context node*, which is not necessarily the input XML document.  Inside

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($FamilySmith)/Children/Child">
```

the path `/Doc/Schools` is looking for the `Doc` element inside the temporary document derived from `$FamilySmith` (so the `value-of` instructions select nothing).  You need to preserve the context node from outside the `for-each` in another variable:

```
<xsl:template match="/Doc">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($FamilySmith)/Children/Child">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:text> goes to (school's name here) </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$doc/Schools/School[Id = current()/School_Id]/Name"/>
        <xsl:text> at (school's address here) </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$doc/Schools/School[Id = current()/School_Id]/Address"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It's clear now. Just to make sure I understand, the difference between the **present case** (i.e., applying the for-each on a local variable) and the **previous case** (where both nodes, "FamilySmith" and "Schools" are both in the same document), is that the latter case have a common top node "Doc". This is not clear in when FamilySmith is placed elsewhere.

Comment: @Bumblevee effectively, yes.  The difference is that the `Doc` element and the `Children` element belong to different documents, and the meaning of `/` changes depending which document the current context node belongs to.